# battery module to control charger to chrge till specific percentage

Tags: power-management, battery

I wanted to ask if there is a battery software which limits the laptop to charge till only 80% just like what happens in samsung eco mode, I have a old laptop about 6 years old and don't want to degrade the battery but sometimes i just forget to plug it out while working it would be great if anyone would help.

I have a samsung notebook 3(the launnched in 2015/2014) (intel core i3 2357m)

Comment: There might be a setting in the computer BIOS, especially in newer laptops. I am not aware of controls at the software level - this probably will not happen, because charging is controlled by the computer hardware, not the OS.

Answer (score 0):

[TLP](https://linrunner.de/tlp/) 1.4 will add charge thresholds for Samsung laptops. You're welcome to participate in the [test](https://gist.github.com/linrunner/2ead4b591eed33055cf86a38ccc73949).

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try the above method

Comment: When are your test results coming in?

Comment: actually a day before yesterday i was playing around in BIOS and I came upon "Battery Life Extension " and i turned it on so TLP didn't come to use as such but i appreciate your help thank you very much

Comment: I see. Unfortunately i couldn't find any testers with a Samsung laptop so far. Because of this a test from your side would be very welcome if you can spare a little time. Please disable the BIOS setting before.